# How to convert date with text to completely numerical number?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to completely convert a set of dates to a numerical number. Like for example `July 1, 2018` to `07/01/2018` or `01/07/2018`.

Comment: Apply **Custom Number Format** `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` on cell/cells ☺

Comment: What is actually stored in the cell (an Excel date or a text string)?  If you aren't sure, in another cell, type `=value(a1)` (where "a1" is the cell reference to the date).  If you get a number in the 43000's, it's a date.  In that case, you don't need to convert anything, what you're seeing is just formatting.  Change the format to the one of your choice.  If what's stored is a text string, do you want to just turn it into a different text string or convert it to an actual date, formatted as you want?  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, let us know your locale, because creating a date or date format consistent with your locale is a little different from one not consistent with your locale.

Comment: How about use Text to Columns? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30B14928-5550-41F5-97CA-7A3E9C363ED7

Answer (score 1):

With a ***Text*** date in cell **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)
```

and apply a suitable format to **B1**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Background:**
Excel stores dates as a count of dates with base (zero) at 1900-01-01.
*(Enter a zero in a cell and then set it formatted to date and time -> 1899-12-30 00:00:00)*

How this then is DISPLAYED depends on your locale settings (the default), or what you have set with "Format cell" <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

There is a significant number of problems for Excel (or any other software) to fully recognize dates, as there is a number of ways a date can be formatted at entry.

Which formats Excel accepts also depends on you locale settings (Country choice, language and the dependent specified time/date formats).

My personal opinion is that the only DISTINCTLY recognizable date format is iso-8601  (e.g. as printed by `$ date --iso-8601` or `$ date --iso-8601=seconds` in a linux shell, note that this is based on an ISO standard => `2019-07-13T09:51:05+02:00` for the latter, just the date for the first).

**Answer:**
To get dates recognized as such in Excel you MUST format them accordingly, there is no easy way to achieve this in other ways.
You MAY write simple macros to automate the conversion, but this generally means looking at the data and adjusting the macro code to match. There is no general solution.
Even a valid entry may then require a re-validation of the cell data; e.g. select the cell and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Only then you get the date value present in the cell. This value is used as the cell is referenced; to see the value: if you have the date in cell A1, the type `=A1` in another cell and format that cell as being a number.